# set_exception_handler Not Catching Class Exceptions

Tags: php, php-7

I've searched a lot here and generally, and have tried everything I can think of before posting, but I cannot nut this out. I'm sure a decent php person will know straight away what the issue is , so ...

I have a file *Db.php* which contains `abstract class Db` which has `require_once Config.php`.

*Config.php* contains, among other things:

```
function global_exception_handler($e) {
    mail(ADDR_TO, "Error", "ERROR: $e", "From: ".ADDR_FM);
}

set_exception_handler('global_exception_handler');
```

:: If I throw an exception - eg, `throw new Exception("Test");` - from below this code in *Config.php*, it works (email received).

:: If I throw an exception *outside of the Db class* in *Db.php*, it works.

:: But if I throw an exception *from within the Db class* - eg in the constructor, where I perform a connection test - nothing happens.

Even if I move the `global_exception_handler` function and `set_exception_handler` declaration to the Db class (using the class form `@set_exception_handler(array($this, 'global_exception_handler'))`), it doesn't fire.

I know I must be missing something obvious, though I'm virtually certain this was working before Hostgator upgraded our server from php 5.5 to 7.4.

---

To answer @WesselvanderLinden's questions and code request ...

1. The (very simple) Db class constructor code is executing, and only once; I added trace `mail` alert in there as per the error handler to test for this.
2. The constructor originally had a `Try...Catch` and I was throwing the exception in the `Catch` after a couple of housekeeping statements. I removed all the "noise" and reduced the constructor down to bare-bones.
3. The *Config.php* file is included (`require_once`) in the *Db.php* file and the handler statements are as posted above.

Here's the bare-bones Db class constructor code (with commented run check trace email):

```
require_once "Config.php";

abstract class Db {

    public function __construct() {
        //mail(ADDR_TO, "Database Error", "ERROR!", "From: ".ADDR_FM);
        throw new Exception("Database connection failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Several things can be happening here. The constructor of your abstract class may be overwritten, so that the code in your constructor doesn't execute. Maybe there is a try-catch somewhere, or maybe the order is wrong (e.g. you first throw the exception and then set the exception handler). 
So I think you should add a bit more of your code so we can see what is going on. Add the code for your constructor, and maybe an example implementation of the DB class. Otherwise it's a bit hard to answer :)

Comment: @WesselvanderLinden I'll add to the question, thanks.

Comment: Please post a complete, minimal example.

Comment: Just a few questions: Why are you using `abstract class`? Is there a child-class extending class `Db`? How do you instantiate `Db` class?

Comment: @wayneOS Yes, class `Db` is extended into other Db-based classes, eg `Db_Admin`, `Db_Client`, etc. So `Db` itself is not instantiated.

Comment: @SteveCinq Do the classes `Db_Admin` and `Db_Client` call `parent::__construct ();` in its own constructors?

Comment: @wayneOS `AdminDb` does but I've just checked and `ClientDb_base` - which is inherited by each of the ClientDb classes - doesn't. However, `ClientDb_Mc`, `ClientDb_Bb`, etc - which extend `ClientDb_base` which extends `Db` - _do_ call `parent::__construct();`. But remember that even if this is incorrect, and I'll test it, `AdminDb` exceptions are still not being handled as expected.

Comment: @SteveCinq I have another idea. Have you tried putting the `require_once Config.php` into the constructor of `Db` class? maybe it isn't getting executed by extending another class.

Comment: @wayneOS No, it must be being included because too many other things would break otherwise. `Config.php` contains, constants, paths, credentials, etc.

Comment: @SteveCinq No i mean that you move the `require_once Config.php` from the top of the file into the bracket of the `__constructor` method of your `Db` class. because i think that by extending a a child class with `Db` the `require_once` part outside of the class-declaration won't  get executed.

Comment: Is there any autoloader involved anywhere (either your own or are you using something like composer)? How is your abstract being included in your project? What is the return from the set_exception_handler?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the complete code, ready for copy & paste. I have run it on PHP 7.4.15 on a docker machine and it does what it should.
I also ran it through various other PHP versions on http://phptester.net/ and the output was always the same...

Cannot reproduce your problem.

```
echo 'PHP '.phpversion().PHP_EOL;

function global_exception_handler($e) {
    echo 'exception handler : ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}

abstract class Db {

    public function __construct() {
        //mail(ADDR_TO, "Database Error", "ERROR!", "From: ".ADDR_FM);
        throw new Exception("Database connection failed");
    }
}
class Db2 extends Db {
    
}

set_exception_handler('global_exception_handler');


$db = new Db2();
```

Output of this code on my docker machine:

```
PHP 7.4.15
exception handler : Database connection failed
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, `Db.php` includes `Config.php` (as `require_once`) wherein I set up the global handler. `Config.php` has both the handler function and `set_exception_handler` declaration. I can't see how, but would that be creating any issues?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see

I created `Config.php`:

```
<?php
function global_exception_handler($e) {
    echo ADDR_TO, "Error", "ERROR: $e", "From: ".ADDR_FM;
}
set_exception_handler('global_exception_handler');
?>
```

Then `index.php`;

```
<?php
require_once "Config.php";
const ADDR_TO = "to@example.com";
const ADDR_FM = "from@example.com";

abstract class Db {
    public function __construct() {
        throw new Exception("Database connection failed");
    }
}

class MyDb extends Db {}

$db = new MyDB(); // run construct
?>
```

When I run it I get an output:

```
to@example.comErrorERROR: Exception: Database connection failed in /home/daniil/.../index.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 /home/daniil/.../index.php(19): Db->__construct()
#1 {main}From: from@example.com
```

It seems as you expect